# UnsatisfiedLinkError with Oracle OTT utility

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run Oracle's [Object Type Translator Utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10764/ottutility.htm) (OTT) and getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\ocijdbc11.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3516)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:3512)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:266)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:162)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ott.Konnection.getTheConnection(Konnection.java:102)
    at oracle.ott.Konnection.<init>(Konnection.java:39)
    at oracle.ott.Doit.main(Doit.java:107)
    at oracle.ott.c.CMain.main(CMain.java:9)
```

It was working fine few months ago and no idea why this is giving error now.

Comment: It was working fine on your current machine and Oracle version? The 32/64-bit message suggests something has changed.

Comment: I installed sqlDeveloper , thats it but how it will affect my ott utility?

Comment: Did you install the 32-bit SQL Developer, and a new 32-bit version of Java too? Seems like you were using a 64-bit JDK before?

Comment: I think so... but i tried to install 64 bit jdk now and its seems the issue is still there.

Comment: can anybody throw some light on this ?

Comment: Not really my area, but did you install for user or system; what version(s) does the Java control panel show as enabled; what is JAVA_HOME set to; if you run java -version from the command line which one does it see? (I don't know how the ott.exe is linked to/chooses it's Java instance though; in 12c there's a .bat file so I guess that is more like the Linux shell script, but you're on 11g so that doesn't really help!)

Comment: I tried to isntall oracle instant clinet again and now the error seems to a bit different ..

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>ott config=myconfig.cfg intype=demoin.typ outtype=demoout.typ code=cpp hfile=demo
.h cppfile=demo.cpp ATTRACCESS=private

OTT: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Wed Jul 08 10:49:07 EDT 2015
System default option values taken from: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\precomp\admin\ottcfg.cfg
O2T-1117, Error reported by subsystem:
nullO2T-102, ERROR: Unable to connect to schema "probebuilder"

Comment: Is it getting `probebuilder` from the config file? (Or one of the other files, but that seems most likely). Have you given a valid user/password?

Comment: it is getting it from myconfig.cfg file

Comment: So - is that the right user? Can you connect to SQL\*Plus with the same credentials? This doesn't seem to be anything to do with the original question now.

Comment: userid and password are correct

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out finally that there was some issue with the old setup of instant client 11_2.0, so i installed new instant client 11_2.2 and set all the required environment variables and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Great that you got it working, but from the messages you showed, you were running the full server version of OTT, not one from an instant client installation.

Comment: Hi Alex, 

OTT comes as a part of SDK (full version) but there are few jar files and ottclassess.zip files  that are in instant client bbut not in sdk, so waht i did was i copied the ott from sdk into the instant clinet folder and then ran ott utility and it works fine.